# Qual é a forma correta de se atribuir uma função a um evento HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Na programação sabemos que é possível obter o mesmo resultado seguindo por diferentes caminhos, porém, também existem boas e más práticas.

Existem sites e desenvolvedores que utilizam maneiras diferentes de chamar uma função javascript, como por exemplo:

```
<button onClick="funcao()" id="chamaFuncao">
```

e para chamar a mesma função com jQuery seria:

```
$("#chamaFuncao").click(function(){});
```

Também poderíamos chamá-la com puro javascript, mas para a minha dúvida esses 2 exemplos são o suficiente.

Qual é a melhor forma ou a maneira correta de se chamar uma função?

Na programação existem boas e más praticas, nos exemplos acima será que um dos métodos é uma boa prática e a outro será uma má prática?

Comment: Na verdade as chamadas são diferentes, com funções diferentes. Não há problema em associar um evento no html. Pode até ficar mais claro. Mas às vezes você não quer essa associação desde o começo. Talvez você só quer associar a partir de algum momento, e isso precisa ser feito por JQuery.

Comment: Achei interessante a pergunta, eu sou mais backend então não tenho propriedade para responder mas considero chamar a função por jQuery uma boa prática para "desacoplar" a parte lógica do HTML

Comment: Eu diria que esta pergunta é duplicada de: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25821/129

Comment: Entendo a diferença. 
Mas digamos que a minha necessidade é exibir um alert com uma mensagem x,para isso eu posso criar o alert apartir do jQuery ou então apartir do evento onClick.

A dúvida é: Qual seria a maneira correta(boa prática) e como distinguir quando usar um e quando usar o outro.

Comment: @Sergio 

Esse link responde a minha pergunta!  
Obrigado.

Comment: Eu já respondi a uma pergunta parecida a esta mas no [Stack Overflow em Inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30249207/3624981)