# Select com redirecionamento

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

**Não sei programar!** mas consigo fazer pequenas alterações.
Estou precisando criar um`select` e quando a pessoa escolher o item, ele seja redirecionado

```html
<select>
  <option value="Vilhena">Vilhena</option>
  <option value="Cacoal">Cacoal</option>
  <option value="Cerejeiras">Cerejeiras</option>
</select>
```

Ai quando selecionar Vilhena, ser redirecionado para uma outra página.

Comment: Conseguiste resolver este problema? Alguma das perguntas ajudou a resolver?

Answer (score 4):

Olá, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:
Elabore um javascript.

## JavaScript

```
<script>
            function AbrirSecao(secao){
                window.open(""+secao+"", "_parent");
            }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<select name="unidade" id="unidade" onChange="AbrirSecao(this.value)">
    <option value="">Selecione sua Cidade</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com.br">Sua Cidade 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com.br">Sua Cidade 2</option>
</select>
```

Com isto, ao selecionar a cidade, será redirecionado automaticamente pelo JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Ou se quiser usar jQuery:

```
<select id="selecao">
    <option value="http://www.exemplo.com.br">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.exemplo.com.br">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="http://www.exemplo.com.br">Opção 3</option>
</select>

// requer jquery
<script>
$('#selecao').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também simplesmente colocar um `onclick="location.href='seusite'"` no evento `onclick` do elemento `option`

```html
<select>
  <option value="Vilhena" onclick="location.href='seusite'">Vilhena</option>
  <option value="Cacoal" onclick="location.href='seusite'">Cacoal</option>
  <option value="Cerejeiras" onclick="location.href='seusite'">Cerejeiras</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso usando JavaScript nativo. Ou seja, sem nenhuma biblioteca externa, e sem misturar JavaScript no HTML ([que não é muito aconselhável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25824/129)).

Nesse caso precisas de ter em consideração 3 coisas:

- o que colocar no HTML
- o oscultador de eventos
- onde colocar o JavaScript

No HTML a parte visível é o que está entre `>` e `<` de cada `option`. O que está no `value` é que é importante para a parte da programação. Assim em vez de teres o mesmo no `value` e o texto das `option` coloca no `value` o URL que pretendes. Por exemplo:

```
<option value="/Vilhena.html">Vilhena</option>
```

Para selecionares o elemento podes usar:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
```

Isto ^ vai funcionar bem se só tiveres 1 select na página. Se tiveres mais que um deve dar uma ID ao select (o HTML ficaria: `<select id="meuSelect">`) e podes selecioná-lo assim:

```
var select = document.getElementById('meuSelect');
// ou assim:
var select = document.querySelector('#meuSelect');
```

depois junta-lhe um oscultador de eventos para quando mudar:

```
select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var valor = this.value;
    window.location.href = valor;
});
```

Por fim coloca o script no final da página, antes da tag `</body>`. Dessa maneira o JavaScript é lido com o HTML já carregado na memória.

Answer (score -1):

Uma solução simples que pegar o valor selecionado e seta no window location (que abre na mesma aba):

```html
<select
  onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
>
  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
  <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</option>
  <option value="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</option>
</select>
```

Ou você também pode usar o window open que abre em uma nova aba

```html
<select
  onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, '_blank'));"
  target="_blanck"
>
  <option value="">Selecionar...</option>
  <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</option>
</select>
```