# Como invocar metodos diretamente nos elementos HTML em jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Em javascript eu consigo invocar os metodos normalmente, mas quando utilizo jQuery, ele não funciona.

Por ex.:

```
<a href="#" onclick="meuMetodo()"> Link </a>
```

No javascript os metodos funcionam assim, mas no jQuery não.

Explicando melhor:

na parte do script, eu declaro da seguinte forma:

```
<script...>

$('doc...ready...

function meuMetodo(){

    //corpo do metodo

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onclick="meuMetodo()"> Link </a>

</body>
```

Em javascript, tudo funciona. Mas essa mesma sintaxe em jQuery não está funcionando. Existe uma sintaxe diferente para invocar os metodos em jQuery ou simplesmente nao é possível invocar os metodos atraves dos elementos HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É uma questão de escopo.

Quando tens código dentro de `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` vais ter problemas a aceder funções dentro desse escopo via HTML inline. Daí que é [boa prática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25824/129) adicionar auscultadores de eventos em vez de chamar funções no HTML ([como o @Danylo sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101634/129)).

Mesmo assim, se as funções tiverem no escopo global, ie fora desse `.ready()` não tens problemas. Basicamente deixa dentro desse `.ready()` só as funções que "iniciam" o código e dependem portanto de uma página carregada/completa. O resto deixa fora, em escopo global para o HTML ter acesso.

Um exemplo seria:

```
$(document).ready(meuMetodo);

function meuMetodo(){ // esta função está no escopo global...
    // iniciar o código!

}

function clicado(e){
    // chamada por exemplo via HTML em onclick=
}
```

Comment: Deu certo agora. Colocando o método fora do "ready" de inicialização, ele funciona na chama atraves do elemento.

Gostaria de saber o porquê dessa prática não ser considerada boa. Você sabe?
A maneira mais correta de se programar em jQuery é chamando os elementos dentro do escopo do ready?

Comment: @ArthurCáceres dá uma olhada aqui, a uma explicação boa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25824/129

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('seu seletor').click(function(){
   meuMetodo();
});
```

Comment: Dessa forma funciona, mas eu gostaria de chamar o metodo atraves do elemento, ao inves de chamar o elemento atraves do metodo.

Comment: Danylo, se explicares melhor a resposta vou dar `+1` :)