# Em relação as funções do jQuery, é arriscado usá-las nos elementos inline?

Tags: jquery

Tem uma boa pergunta aqui no Stackoverlow que fala sobre a questão de práticas

[Porque é uma má prática usar Javascript inline?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25821/porque-%C3%A9-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica-usar-javascript-inline)

Porém agora, não querendo olhar a questão da má ou boa prática em si, eu gostaria de saber se é problemático usar eventos do jQuery inline. Ou seja, diretamente nos elementos, através dos métodos de atribuição de eventos que o próprio html fornecesse.

Exemplo. Ao invés de fazer isso:

```
$(function (){

    $('#elemento').click(function (){ 
       $('#outro-elemento').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Fazer isso:

```
<div id="elemento" onclick="$('#outro-elemento').fadeIn()"></div>
```

De fato, eu já vi alguns amigos programadores fazendo isso, e até então tinha funcionado corretamente.

Mas questões que eu gostaria de saber seriam:

- Ao fazer isso, corro algum risco de a função não funcionar, por conta de, para funcionar a atribuição de eventos no jQuery, ter que usar o código dentro de `$(function (){})` ou então `$(document).ready()`?
- Corro riscos ao fazer isso diretamente em elementos criados dinamicamente? Pois geralmente, para os eventos funcionarem em tais elementos, devemos usar `$(document).on('evento', 'elemento_dinamico')`.

Por exemplo. Para atribuir um evento a um elemento dinâmico, eu devo usar o `on`.

```
$('#container').append('<a class="teste">teste</a>');

$('#container').on('click', '.teste', function () {
      $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Mas eu também poderia (sem riscos de erro), adicioná-lo inline, assim?

```
$('#container').append('<a class="teste" onclick="$(this).fadeOut()">teste</a>');
```

Comment: Nunca tinha visto isso, que coisa feia.

Comment: Fala isso não, kkkk. Eu já vi uns colegas fazendo isso ;). O chefe pediu para acelerar o processo, ninguém quer saber de boas práticas.

Answer (score 0):

Pense assim se você tivesse um arquivo main.js contendo todas as funções
 de sua aplicação, seria mais fácil para fazer a manutenção, agora imagine
 o mesmo código em diversas páginas e você tem que fazer manutenção.

Agora imagine você fazendo manutenção em um sistema de terceiros, a primeira
 reclamação sua seria o layout ou o código?

Boas Práticas não é uma regra, porém ajuda muito e quem faz acaba se adequando
 e criando bom padrão aceito no mercado aonde algumas Empresa possuem esta
 preocupação, lembrando não é regra.